# How to sent data triggered lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to send changed data triggered lambda function from DynamoDb. Then ı want to save this changed data different DynamoDb tables.
**Programming Language:** NodeJs

**DynomaDb**
Stream enabled: Yes
View type:  New and old images

**Lambda Function**

```
'use strict';

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        console.log(record.eventID);
        console.log(record.eventName);
        console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);
    });
    callback(null, `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`);
};
```

it is not working.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan 
'use strict';

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        console.log(record.eventID);
        console.log(record.eventName);
        console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);
    });
    callback(null, `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`);
};

Comment: But it was throw error @VijayanathViswanathan

Comment: Please update your code in question itself so that it would help for all others in the community. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @VijayanathViswanathan :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB streams and Lambda can be used for the above use case.

1) Enable the DynamoDB streams on Dynamodb table to stream the data

2) Create a Lambda function to consume the stream and write to another DynamoDB table. The Lambda function can be created in many programming languages (API). You can use **AWS SDK** to create the lambda function.

Refer the below links for more details.

[Full documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html)

[Enable Streams and Lambda - Cross region replication use case](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/)

**Stream View Type:-**

> StreamViewType—specifies the information that will be written to the
>   stream whenever data in the table is modified:
>
> KEYS_ONLY—only the key attributes of the modified item.
>
> NEW_IMAGE—the entire item, as it appears after it was modified.
>
> OLD_IMAGE—the entire item, as it appeared before it was modified.
>
> NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES—both the new and the old images of the item.

**Event Name:-**

`record.eventName` should have **MODIFY** when the data is updated in the DynamoDB table.

`record.dynamodb` should have the values based on the Stream view type. If you have selected `NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES`, then it should have both old and new values.

> eventName — (String) The type of data modification that was performed
>   on the DynamoDB table:
>
> INSERT - a new item was added to the table.
>
> MODIFY - one or more of an existing item's attributes were modified.
>
> REMOVE - the item was deleted from the table

Comment: ı use node js. The stream is enabled and stream view type new_and_old_images. But ı don't understand how lambda functions catch changed data? @notionquest

Comment: @BurhanYılmaz Updated the details to identify the event name (INSERT, MODIFY or REMOVE).

Answer (score 0):

You want to change it to this:

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    event.Records.forEach(function(record) {
        console.log(record.eventID);
        console.log(record.eventName);
        console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);
    });
    callback(null, "message");
};
```